# php array_push not functioning

Tags: php, array-push

I have a script i'm working on thats automaticly building team pools. There is several clubs and each club can have multiple teams. Multiple teams in one pool from the same club are not allowed. This is where my script goes wrong. It checks if the team is in the same club that the other teams in the same pool (16 pools,4 teams per pool).

It pops the teamid from an array and compares club ID's in DB, if they have same club ID the teamID gets pushed back into the array and repeats untill it finds team in different club.

Somehow it(sometimes?) fails to push the team back into array and i cannot see what i have done wrong. Is this happens once, i end up with a team less, if it happens more then once, the last(or2 last) pools have empty value's wich will cause the while loop to go forever.

This is a code snippet that compares the team and club ID's.

```
        //TeamA
        //set dummyteam if needed, else choose from array
        if($dummy != 0){
            $teamA = "73";
            --$dummy;
        }
        else{
            $teamA = array_pop($teams);
        }

        $teamB = array_pop($teams);
        //TeamB
        //is TeamB in different club then Team A?
        $ABteamisdifferent = 0;
        while($ABteamisdifferent == 0){
            if(GetClubID($teamA) == GetClubID($teamB)){
                    $teams[] = $teamB;
                    shuffle($teams);
                    $ABteamisdifferent = 0;
                    $teamB = array_pop($teams);

            }
            else{
                $ABteamisdifferent = 1;
            }
        }
        ......
```

[Full code link](http://s3.h4u.be/~dfk/tmp/inarray/createpool.txt)

[Script output](http://s3.h4u.be/~dfk/tmp/inarray/output.txt)

[Function Code](http://s3.h4u.be/~dfk/tmp/inarray/func.txt)

I've wasted 3 hours trying to fix this, but i'm probably overlooking something stupid. Still, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're adding the team to the `$team` array. Is that what you meant, or did you mean to push it to the `$teams` array instead?

Comment: omg, i figured i overlooked something, but this... i feel ashamed now. Thx for the tip :)

Comment: While i initially thought this solved the problem (it was part of the problem) it still sometimes locks up in infinite while loop. I adjusted code in question and external files to reflect code changes.

Comment: If the array contains only teams of the same club, you will get an endless loop. So if teams are picked from this array, eventually, maybe, you may be left with an array that only contains teams (or a team) that has the same club as TeamA. Anyway, I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but it seems to be an overly complex piece of code with a lot of repetition in it. Perhaps it's a good time to take a step back, and maybe rewrite the logic from scratch.

Comment: Also, since this question has changed quite a lot since the original team/teams mixup, and even received an answer for the initial version, it may be better to close/accept this one and write a new one if you're still stuck.

Comment: Hi GolezTroll, thank you for your reply. i'll be putting the while loops in a function as well, for the rest there is little i can do to further optimize the script in the curretn form in term of less code. I'll brainstorm some more tomorrow on how i can solve the open issue. Thx for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the team back into a `$team` variables instead of `$teams`. Simply change the following line:

```
$team[] = $teamB;
```

to:

```
$teams[] = $teamB;
```

Comment: While i initially thought this solved the problem (it was part of the problem) it still sometimes locks up in infinite while loop. I adjusted code in question and external files to reflect code changes.